# Set model field default to value from foreign key instance

Tags: python, django, graphene-python

Working on a Django app with two models (A and B), B has a field `link` which is a foreign key relationship to A:

```
# models.py
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    my_bool = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class B(models.Model):
    link = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b_bool = models.BooleanField(default=link.my_bool) # Error!
```

I would like for the `b_bool` field to have the linked `my_bool` value as a *default* **if no** `B.b_bool` is provided via graphene mutation.

Currently, using `link.my_bool` as a default raises the following error when making migrations:

```
AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'my_bool'
```

Comment: try: `link__my_bool`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it will work like that. Instead, try overriding [**`save()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) method:

```
class B(models.Model):
    link = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b_bool = models.BooleanField(default=False)

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
     if not self.b_bool:
         self.b_bool = self.link.my_bool
     super(B, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```